# drawImage to resize all pictures to same width

Tags: javascript, drawimage

Im using drawImage to "resize" the image with ;

```
img.onload = function(){
            var width = img.width * 0.16,
                height = img.height * 0.16;

            canvas.width = width,
            canvas.height = height;


            ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
        }
```

Whenever I use it like this, it shows the image nicely

But whenever i do fixed width and height it shows the init bit blurry
    img.onload = function(){

```
            ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 56, 56);
        }
```

So I want fixed height and width but must show not blurry

Answer (score 0):

Your first version sets the canvas's width and height to be the same dimensions as those of the image, so when you draw the image, no scaling is performed (actually, your img's width and height are scaled down by 16%, or 0.16, to match the value you specify, but it does not scale your image down when drawing into the canvas because the last 2 arguments of `drawImage()` match the dimensions of the canvas).

```
img.onload = function(){
            var width = img.width * 0.16,
                height = img.height * 0.16;

            canvas.width = width, // canvas's width === img's width
            canvas.height = height; // canvas's heeight === img's height


            ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height); // draw img at the same dimensions as those of the canvas => no scaling => no blur
        }
```

Whereas, your second version draws the image at 56x56 size, this does not match the canvas' dimensions, hence the image is scaled down, so it appears a little blurry.

```
   img.onload = function(){

        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 56, 56); // last 2 arguments tell the browser to draw the image at 56x56 px dimensions
    }
```

Comment: Thanks  but i kind of noticed that, the question is how to do this to work it?

Comment: @JohnSmiths don't scale it too much